# Storing a worksheet name for use in another sub

Tags: variables, excel, public, vba

I'm using one sub-procedure to store filepaths/workbooks and worksheets in Public variables which can then be accessed by other sub procedures in the module. Here is some example code:

```
Public myfp As String
Public mywb As Workbook
Public myws As Worksheet

Sub FilePaths()
    myfp = Application.GetOpenFileName(Title:="Please select the file.")
    Set mywb = Workbooks.Open(myfp, 0)
    If Left(mywb.Sheets(1).Name, 2) = "01" Then
        Set myws = mywb.Sheets(1)
    Else
        Set myws = mywb.Sheets(2)
    End If
    mywb.Saved = True
    mywb.Close
Exit Sub

Sub Stuff()
    Dim wb As WorkBook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
    ws.Range("A1").Value = wb.ws.Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

So my first sub determines which sheet I need and my second sub should put the value of this sheets cell into my sheet. However all I get is errors. I figure this may be because I have to open the file so I tried something I know should work:

```
SUb Stuff()
    Range("A1").Formula = "='[" & myfp & "]" & myws & "'!A1"
End Sub
```

However this also doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test example, you are using the `wb` and `ws` objects, not their names. Try this:

```
Public myfp As String
Public myWbName As String
Public myWsName As String

Sub FilePaths()
Dim myWb As Workbook

myfp = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Please select the file.")
Set myWb = Workbooks.Open(myfp, 0)
myWbName = myWb.Name
If Left(myWb.Sheets(1).Name, 2) = "01" Then
    myWsName = myWb.Sheets(1)
Else
    myWsName = myWb.Sheets(2).Name
End If
myWb.Saved = True
myWb.Close
End Sub

Sub Stuff()
    Range("A1").Formula = "='[" & myfp & "]" & myWsName & "'!A1"
End Sub
```

Comment: This seems to only partly work, using that bottom 'stuff' sub, I get this in the formula bar `='[C:\MacroFiles\Files\[My Long File Name 20 08 2013.xlsx]01Sheet]My Long File Name 2'!A1` so for some reason it seems to be mucking up and I have no idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `wb` qualifier from in front of your `ws` object.

Change this:

```
ws.Range("A1").Value = wb.ws.Range("A1").Value
```

To this:

```
ws.Range("A1").Value = ws.Range("A1").Value
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first Stuff, once ws has been Set, use:
something = ws.Range("A1").Value

you don't need wb.ws

In the second Stuff, you need to use a string variable in creating a Formula, **myws.Name** rather than **myws**.